# How do I define HTML entity references inside a valid XML document?

Tags: xml, xhtml, dtd

I need to be able to reference named HTML entities like `&bull;` instead of the Unicode alternative `&#8226;` in an XML document.  I have control over some parts of the XML document, such as defining the `DOCTYPE`, but doing a find-and-replace in the actual XML is not an option.  I can get some elements like `&nbsp;` and `&amp;` by including the XHTML transitional DOCTYPE, but I need to define more manually.  How do I do this?

-- EDIT --

Thanks to Jim's answer, here's what I ended up with.  This is great because I can utilize the XHTML transitional entities, and also add my own:

```
<!DOCTYPE
   html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
   [
      <!ENTITY bull  "&#8226;">
      <!ENTITY ldquo "&#8220;">
      <!ENTITY rdquo "&#8221;">
      ... etc ...
   ]
>
```

Comment: If you end up using a lot of entity declarations, consider putting them in a separate file and then using a parameter entity to reference them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you can modify the the XML to include an inline DTD you can define the entities there:

```
<!DOCTYPE yourRootElement [
    <!ENTITY bull "&#8226;">
    ....
]>
```

Comment: This is magic! It can be used to build android manifest files as well, makes it easy to create a template without making any mistakes on the package name or the like...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not cetain, but I think the XHTML DTD's should give you quite a few entities (253):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Entities_representing_special_characters_in_XHTML

Also in the w3 spec, there is a mention of additional DTD's for special characters etc.
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/dtd_module_defs.html#a_dtd_xhtml_character_entities

However I haven't been able to find an implementation example of the special character DTDs.

---

***Edit by DevNull***

Here is an extremely generic example implementation of one of the entity DTD modules. To implement, you only need to add a parameter entity pointing to the module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [
<!ELEMENT test (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY % xhtml-special SYSTEM "xhtml-special.ent">
%xhtml-special;
]>
<test>Here is a left double quote: &ldquo;</test>
```

Comment: I added an example of an implementation. I hope you don't mind. If this isn't what you meant, please feel free to delete my edit.

Comment: Cool, nice one @DevNull didn't know you could do that. So does "test (#PCDATA)" tell the parser that "test" is a Parsed Character Data?

Comment: It means that the `test` element can contain "parsed character data" (plain text).

Comment: The DOM (Chrome) looks then like:                                                             `<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">                                                                                                                   <html> <head></head><body>] &gt;`                                                                                                                     So it is not parsed properly and redundant ]> characters are inserted into body

Comment: FileNotFoundException: xhtml-special.ent