# Simple way to do XML with HTML codes?

Tags: java, html, xml

I have an XML file, sample.xml, that contains the following:

```
<Tokens>
   <Token>Hello&nbsp;World</Token>
</Tokens>
```

I want to parse it - but get errors when it gets to the NBSP

I do not have access to the schema for the XML I am using (the one that defines Token or Tokens).

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = docBuilder.parse("sample.xml");
```

Since I do not have the Schema for my XML document, I was wondering if there is a way to have it completely ignore the HTML special characters while parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML, `&nbsp;` is an entity reference, but an undefined one, unless you provide a definition. You cannot make an XML parser ignore them, but you can define them, e.g. starting your document with

```
<!DOCTYPE Tokens [<!ENTITY nbsp "&#xa0;">]>
```

However, this is probably not useful if you are generating the XML file. You might just as well generate a document containing the real character “ ” U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE, or the character reference `&#xa0;` or its decimal equivalent `&#160;`.

Cf. to question [How do I define HTML entity references inside a valid XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508860/how-do-i-define-html-entity-references-inside-a-valid-xml-document)

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is impossible because to parse ask XML the entity must have a definition somewhere. To parse it as other than XML you need to write your own parser, or use a tolerant parser. XML is not tag soup.

Answer (score 0):

XML doesn’t support `&nbsp`, although XHTML does. Check the [predefined entities in XML list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

The solution is to use the Unicode non-breaking space character `&#160` while building XML; instead. In some cases a plain space works too (`&#32`;). Before parsing the XML you can try to replace `&nbsp` with a ' '-space though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Reedwald. But as a workaround you can read the file as string and replace the   with spaces before parsing the document.