# Can I declare my own named entities in HTML?

Tags: html-entities

So for example, if I wanted to declare `&#hiragana_a;` as an entity that corresponds to `&#12354;`.

Is this possible in HTML?

The list of named entities for HTML5 can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references).

This is possible using XML with a custom DTD.

So what if I used XHTML5? Could I specify a custom DTD with custom named entities?

Comment: It is; however, possible with XML, as shown in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508860/how-do-i-define-html-entity-references-inside-a-valid-xml-document

So why not HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out how to it, it required using XHTML.

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY test "It worked">
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>HTML Entities</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>&test;</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

This worked when I tested it using Google Chrome.

Comment: Great idea! I wish that were the standard semantics. But I've tried it in an android webview; and it didn't work. Even with the doctype fragment and the xml ns declaration you suggest, android studio flagged an "undefined entity", and the runtime ignored my definition.