# BeautifulSoup (bs4) XML parser removes html entities

Tags: python, xml, html-entities, beautifulsoup

look at this example:

```py
# xml parser
bs4.BeautifulSoup('<price>&pound;4</price>', 'xml')

# prints:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<price>4</price>
```

```py
# html (lxml) parser
bs4.BeautifulSoup('<span>&pound;4</span>', 'lxml')

# prints:
<html><body><span>£4</span></body></html>
```

Notice the `£` sign. Why the XML parser removes it? What should I do to have it in the output? I need `xml` parsing, because the document contains some paired tags which are wrongly parsed by `lxml` parser (e.g. `<link>`).

Comment: Do you have to use the xml parser?

Answer (score 0):

The `&pound;` is not a standard XML entity - use for example `&#163;` instead. `&pound;` is a HTML entity, and can't be used without declaring (or embedding) them in a DTD.

Edit: See for example [How do I define HTML entity references inside a valid XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508860/how-do-i-define-html-entity-references-inside-a-valid-xml-document)

Comment: HI, thanks for reply. You are probably right, but `BS` stil not paring it correctly `bs4.BeautifulSoup('<!DOCTYPE item [ <!ENTITY pound "&#163;"> ]><item>&pound;4</item>', 'xml')` prints `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE item><item>4</item>`

Comment: ..Could you use `&#163;` in the input instead, or massaging the input HTML in some other way?