# dash operator causes error “xml parsing error :not well-formed”

Tags: xml, validation, parsing

I am replalcing the - special character with & ndash; html entity in my XML content . If i am trying to open the XML file in browser it is throwing the below error.

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location:Line Number 14, Column 35: SDI Bullet IR Camera Full HD 1080P 1920x10803.3-12mm Varifocal Lens 1/3& ndash; 2MP CMOS36 IR LEDs Outdoor / Indoor ----------------------------------^ .

I am new to XML. My XML version is "1.0". Please help.

Comment: Remove the space after the `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a handful of predefined entities such as `&lt;`, `&gt;` etc, you cannot use entities in XML unless you declare them in the DOCTYPE declaration. See for example

[How do I define HTML entity references inside a valid XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508860/how-do-i-define-html-entity-references-inside-a-valid-xml-document)